# Is there a way to check the wifi antennas on my laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a laptop with 3 wifi antennas connected to an Intel Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 AGN board. I had the CPU fan changed under warranty and I watched (in horror) as the laptop technician ripped the wifi antennas out by pulling the cables to make room for the fan change.

Ever since I cannot get the speeds I used to get when transferring files from my server. I used to get around 38-40MB/s sustained transfers on large files before. Now I get around 17MB/s so I am convinced that something's wrong. Checking with another laptop I get the 38MB/s so the router (Linksys E4200) is fine. Oh and my laptop says I am connected at 450Mbps but as soon as a transfer happens that drops to sometimes 364Mbps, 360Mbps or 300Mbps. But even with 300Mbps I should have been able to get 30+MB/s transfers

Can anyone recommend a way to check the antennas and give me some values such as the SNR (signal to noise ratio) or the RSSI values? It would be great if there was a way to maybe isolate them and use them one by one to identify the faulty antenna cable? I would rather not unplug them as the connectors are so delicate.

Also what transfer speeds in MB/s should I be getting when connected at 450Mbps?

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't contacted the technician that RIPPED the wifi antennas and asked him what he did exactly?

Comment: routing of the antenna wires is important, be sure they are not close (next to) any other hardware.

Comment: @Sickest I live in a country where everything is done in an amateur way. Of course I contacted them but they act as if everything was done properly. So I am afraid to let them open the laptop again. Luckily I managed to convince them to give me the rest of the antennas in the antenna replacement kit so I will attempt to change them myself. But before I do that I was looking for a way to test them in a scientific way that is get hard measurements of the performance of the antennas before replacing them again